# Google's example of Fragments: maintaining selected item in list when changing orientation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have been working on some samples with ContentProviders, loaders, cursors and fragments. I have been using Google's example of [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentLayoutSupport.html). Keep in mind this is with the v4 support library.

Their example preserves the selected item when switcing orientation and the fragment that is displayed is for the preserved selected item.

**In their code, what is giving them this capability? I have been trying to figure this out and just can't find it.**

What i have wrote will still have the item highlighted in the list but the fragment that is displayed is not the details for the selected item... it is just the details for the first item.

Thanks

---

**Solution:** I was forgetting to set `mCurCheckPosition` = `index` in the `showDetails` method... lol.

Comment: that part `mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);` and later `showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);` said curChoice is filled by `outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);`

Comment: That is what i thought, but i tried it yesterday and it did not work. However, i re-visited it today because you pointed it out as well. When i re-visited i saw that i had forgotton to set `mCurCheckPosition` = `index` in the `showDetails` method... lol. So my `mCurCheckPosition` was always 0. Thanks for the help. If you post this as the answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onSaveInstanceState`, call

```
outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
```

This saves data in the bundle you're given in `onActivityCreated`:

```
mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
```

Later, you can use this value, in this case:

```
showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
```